# lottie files not displaying correctly [ERROR 404 Not found]

Tags: html, css, json, lottie

I m trying to add lottie files in my website.

When I use `<lottie-player autoplay hover class="home-icon" style = "width : 30px;" src="https://assets2.lottiefiles.com/private_files/lf30_acah1toy.json"></lottie-player>`. it **WORKS**

But when I use `<lottie-player autoplay hover class="linkedin-icon" style = "width : 40px;" src="../static/lottie/homeIcon.json"></lottie-player>` **NOTHING IS RENDERED** on my screen

On the console I have two errors message [first](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gEQqu.png) and [second](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MaSbu.png)...
What am I missing ?

Thanks for helping

Comment: 404 means it is not found so go find it and add a proper reference?

Comment: Does not feel like we have enough information to assist you properly and perhaps two entirely unrelated issues?